# How to output htmls files from Lightweight markdown files using Oxygen XML editor 20.0?

Tags: html, markdown

Resources:
- Lightweight dita code sample files from https://github.com/DITAWriter/LwDITA_Code_Samples
- Oxygen XML editor 20.0
- DITA-OT 3.0.3

Procedure:
1. Run the markdown files [TRS-80 Expansion Module (MDITA Expanded - With Keys)]. 
Open TRS-80 Expansion Module (MDITA Expanded - With Keys)\index.md in Oxygen 20.0, and try to transform to html.

Error comes:
[oxygen 20.0 error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxkVN.png)

2. I made a ditamap using markdown files in directory \TRS-80 Expansion Module (MDITA Expanded - With Keys), and transform the map to html.
   Also failed.

Question:
1. Using the lightweight dita markdown sample files, how to convert to html files, actually? Is there anything I did wrong?
2. If I have markdown topic files using lightweight dita, what is the correct way to make them convert to other formats, such as html, PDF?

Thanks in advance!